# PyQt : How to set up a widget hidding an other widget if it's visible?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Let's say I created two QObject in my interface (ui). I would like to connect these two widgets and let them controling each other depending on their visual status. If one is hidden, the other one must be visible. And vice versa.

Can you help me ? :)

Thanks !

Nico

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible solution: Sublclass widgets and override `hideEvent` and `showEvent`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class CustomWidget(QtGui.QLabel):
    signal_hided = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    signal_shown = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        print 'hideEvent'
        super(CustomWidget, self).hideEvent(event)
        self.signal_hided.emit()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        print 'showEvent'
        super(CustomWidget, self).showEvent(event)
        self.signal_shown.emit()


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.widget1 = CustomWidget('Widget1')
        self.widget2 = CustomWidget('Widget2')

        # connect signals, so if one widget is hidden then other is shown
        self.widget1.signal_hided.connect(self.widget2.show)
        self.widget2.signal_hided.connect(self.widget1.show)
        self.widget2.signal_shown.connect(self.widget1.hide)
        self.widget1.signal_shown.connect(self.widget2.hide)

        # some test code
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget1)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.do_test)

    def do_test(self):
        if self.widget1.isHidden():
            self.widget1.show()
        else:
            self.widget2.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWidget()
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```